# AJAX reloading content thats being sent from instance PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I want to reload the data every  1 minute, using `setInterval`, but this is the way I am using to get my data on the table:

```
Class Tournaments
{
    private $controller = null;

    function __construct($instance = FALSE)
    {

        $this->controller = new Controller();

        if ($instance)
        {
            return $this->getLatestTournaments();
        }
    }

    private function getLatestTournaments() 
    {
        $fetch = $this->controller->db->fetch("argonite_tournament_history", array(), $single = FALSE, $limit = 5);

        while ($row = $fetch->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            Template::drawTableRow (
                $row['name'], 
                $row['winner'], 
                $row['kills'], 
                $row['reward']
            );          
        }
    }

}
```

and now the HTML PART:

```
        <div class="argonite_tables" >
                <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                           Tournament Name
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            Winner
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Kills
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Reward
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>                       
                    </tr>
                    <? new Tournaments(TRUE); ?>
                </table>
        </div>
```

basically, I am making a new instance to show the data up.
Therefore, to use ajax to reload messages, I need to manually add the received data into the tables.

Is it possible to reload using ajax with that structure?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you can use ajax to reload data every time here is simple example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
// write a simple function to call it with setInterval function in javascript
function loadData(page)

        {

            loading_show();



            $.ajax(

                {

                    type:"POST",

                    url:"load_data.php",//write your query string and call function ex: loaddata.php/class/function/parameters.. etc

                    data:"page="+page,// optional parameters you can pass into otherwise you can use json to send multiple variables



                    success:function(data)

                    {



                                $("#container").html(data);





                    }


                });

        }
 setInterval(loadData, 5000); // 5 secs interval
});


</script>
```

Not tested hope this idea would help you to write code as you like and call function and load with ajax